# JPanel only showing one object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've made 20 objects from my Ball class, as I need 20 balls bouncing around on the screen, but right now it only shows 1 ball bouncing around.
I think it has something to do with 20 JPanels being added and they are overlapping each other, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
  package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * Created by John on 25/02/2015.
 */
public class Ball extends JComponent{
    int _speedX;
    int _speedY;
    int _size;
    int _x;
    int _y;
    Color _color;
    int _windowX;
    int _windowY;

    Ball(int x, int y, int sz, int sX, int sY, Color c, int windowX, int windowY){
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _speedX = sX;
        _speedY = sY;
        _size = sz;
        _color = c;
        _windowX = windowX;
        _windowY = windowY;
        setForeground(_color);
    }

    public void update(){

            _x = _x + _speedX;
            _y = _y + _speedY;

            if (_x<0 || _x>_windowX-_size){
                _speedX*=-1;
            }

            if (_y<=0 || _y>_windowY-_size){
                _speedY*=-1;
            }



            this.repaint();


    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
        // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.fillOval(_x, _y, _size, _size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title"); //create a new window and set title on window
        frame.setSize(600, 600); //set size of window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //set the window to close when the cross in the corner is pressed
        frame.setVisible(true); //make the window visible
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        Ball[] balls = new Ball[20];

        for(int i = 0; i<20;i++){

            balls[i] = new Ball(randInt(0,600),randInt(0,600),randInt(10,20),randInt(1,8), randInt(1,8),Color.yellow,600,600);
            panel.add(balls[i]);

        }



    while(true){

        for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
            balls[i].update();

        }
        panel.repaint();
        try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I had a similar project a while back and, if I recall correctly, the same problem was fixed by using `paintComponent(Graphics g)` rather than `paint` or `paintComponents()`. Maybe try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I've already tried that, didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

- Don't make Ball extend JComponent or JPanel, but instead make it a logical non-component class.
- Create a Drawing class that extends JPanel and draw in its `paintComponent` method, not its `paint(...)` method. This will lead to smoother animation.
- Create an `ArrayList<Ball>` of your Ball objects and draw them inside of the `paintComponent(...)` method override by iterating through the list.
- Same for moving the Balls held by the List.
- Use a Swing Timer to drive your animation, not a `while (true)` loop. If you make one mistake with that loop, you'll freeze your GUI rendering it non-functioning, and so the Swing Timer is a much safer way to do this.

Comment: 1+, for the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

> it only shows 1 ball bouncing around.

I'm surprised you even see one. You shouldn't see any.

> I think it has something to do with 20 JPanels being added and they are overlapping each other,

The problem is that by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. When you add a component to the panel the panel will respect the preferred size of the component. You are using a custom component and the default size is (0, 0) since you didn't provide one.

If you want to continue this approach by using a custom component then you need to:

1. use the properties of the component to control the size and location of the component on the panel. That is you can use the `setSize(...)` method and `setLocation(...)` method. You don't need your _x, _y and _size variables. You also don't need the color variable because you can use `setForeground(...)` to set the color of your component.
2. Override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the ball.
3. Override the 'paintComponent(...)` method to fill the oval with an x/y value of 0, since the painting needs to be done relative to the ball, not the panel.
4. In the `update()` method you use the `setLocation(...)` method to set the location of the component on the panel.

Now you also need to use a null layout on your panel so the balls can move randomly.

I don't recommend this approach for your final solution, but it is a good exercise to implement this logic to understand how you might go about creating a custom component and how painting is done on this component. Understanding this concept will help you better understand how Swing works in general.